# Getting error with module not being found in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

Getting error with module not being found in node. I'm using inquirer to collect info in node to generate a read me with that info. I feel like I'm calling the module correctly and it should be working(famous last words) but it gives me an error saying

> Error: Cannot find module './createMarkdown'.

Tried changing the way I'm calling it like just 'createMarkdown' and it's still giving the same error.

```js
// This is the index.js file that im running using node index.js

const readMeLayout = require('./createMarkdown');
const fs = require('fs');
const inquirer = require('inquirer');

const questions = [
    {
        type: 'input',
        name: 'name',
        message: 'What is your name?',
        validate: (value) => {
            if (value) { return true }
            else { return "Name Required" }
        }
    },
    {
        type: 'input',
        name: 'title',
        message: 'What is the title of your project?',
        validate: (value) => {
            if (value) { return true }
            else { return "Title Required" }
        }
    },
    {
        type: 'input',
        name: 'description',
        message: 'What would you describe your project as?',
        validate: (value) => {
            if (value) { return true }
            else { return "Description Required" }
        }
    },
    {
        type: 'input',
        name: 'install',
        message: 'What are your installation instructions?',
    },
    {
        type: 'input',
        name: 'usage',
        message: 'How was your project designed to be used?',
    },
    {
        type: 'input',
        name: 'contributing',
        message: 'How can one contribute to your project?',
    },
    {
        type: 'list',
        name: 'license',
        message: 'Provide license information.',
        choices: ["MIT", "Mozilla_Public", "GNU_Affero General Public Licence v3", "GNU_General Public License v2", "GNU_Lesser General Public License v2.1", "Apache_2.0",]
    },
    {
        type: 'input',
        name: 'github',
        message: 'Enter your GitHub Username.',
        validate: (value) => {
            if (value) { return true }
            else { return "Github required" }
        }
    },
    {
        type: 'input',
        name: 'questions',
        message: 'Enter your email so others can reach you if they have questions.',
    },
];

function writeToFile(fileName, data) {
    fs.writeFile(fileName, data, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
    console.log('README created.');
}

function init() {
    inquirer.prompt(questions)
        .then((answers => {
            const readme = readMeLayout(answers);
            writeToFile("README.md", readme);
        }));
}

init();

// this is the module for the layout of the readme file

const readMeLayout = data => {
  const { title, description, usage, installation, license, contributing, name, github, email } = data;
  return `
  # ${title}
  -------------------

  ## Table of Contents  
  ----------------------
  - [Description](#description) 
  - [Usage](#usage)  
  - [Installation](#installation)  
  - [License](#license)  
  - [Contributing](#contributing)  
  - [Questions](#questions)  
    

  ### Description  
  -------------------
  ${description}

  ### Usage  
  ------------
  ${usage}
 
  ### Installation  
  -------------------
  ${installation}

  ### License
  --------------
  ![${license}](https://img.shields.io/badge/license-${license}-blue)

  ### Contributing 
  ------------------

  ### Contact Information
  -------------------------
  ### Github: [${name}](https://github.com/${github})
  #### Email: ${email}
`;
}

module.exports = readMeLayout;
```

Comment: Did you check for the file name `createMarkdown.js`? It probably seems like a file name issue. If the file name is correct, check if the file is present in the same directory as `index.js` is present.

Comment: Yeah I ended up just being in the wrong dir when I called it and ended up not having another module installed in the right dir. A lesson in making sure I'm in the right spot lol

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had been in the wrong dir showing node modules but didnt install inquirer on the working dir.